# pde question of analytic solution

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Show that the following PDE has a real analytic solution near (0, 0):
**$u_y = u_x$, with $u(x, 0) = f(x)$,**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the gneral solution $u(x,y) =h(x+y)$ where $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable function. But $f(x) =u(x,0) =h(x)$ therefore $h=f$ and the solution is $u(x,y)=f(x+y).$